# Php variable global and static

Tags: php, variables

I am new to PHP. 
I'm studying variables scopes.

> A variable declared outside a function has a GLOBAL SCOPE and can only
>   be accessed outside a function.
>
> A variable declared within a function has a LOCAL SCOPE and can only
>   be accessed within that function.
>
> The global keyword is used to access a global variable from within a
>   function.
>
> To do this, use the global keyword before the variables (inside the
>   function)
>
> Normally, when a function is completed/executed, all of its variables
>   are deleted. However, sometimes we want a local variable NOT to be deleted. We need it for a further job.

I need to declare variable within function to be global so I can get access to it from outside the function and to be static at the same time so I can keep the value of the variable after execution of the function and use it again. 
I tried

```
global static $x;
```

but it doesn't work.

I need to know if I'm thinking in wrong way case I'm new to PHP.

```
<?php 
$x = 5;
function myTest() {

   echo "x is equal to".$GLOBALS['x']."";
   $GLOBALS['x']++;

} 
myTest();
myText();

?>
```

it executes only the first myTest().
and the second one display an error 
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function myText()

Comment: why do you need to declare the variable globally within a function? can't you declare it in global scope?

Comment: Global variables remains after a function has executed, so why do you need them to be static as well?

Comment: If I have many functions like 20 , 30 functions it will be bad solution to declare variables outside functions it would be a big mess!

Comment: @MarkBaker
Thaaanks ! I didn't know that global variables remains after function execution.

Comment: if you have 20, 30 functions means you go for OOPs and declare the variable as class member.

Comment: global is key word to access the globally declare the variable access with in the function. or you can access via $_GLOBAL['x']

Comment: @MarkBaker I have updated the question please take a look. it doesn't work to execute function twice

Comment: @KareemAbdelwahed because there is no function defined as `function myText()` or at least you didn't write it here!! maybe you wanted to write `myTest();`

Comment: @AsifRahaman I'm sorry I didn't recognize the misspelling. 
Thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

just declare it in global scope then use `$GLOBALS[]` array or `global` keyword to use that variable in a function. And as they hold the value even after function execution you don't need `static` keyword as well.

study [$GLOBALS](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php), [Variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Comment: please take a look after I edited the question to understand what is the problem I have.

Comment: @KareemAbdelwahed maybe you have done a typing mistake while calling the function because first you've defined `myTest()` function then you called this function but afterwards you called another function called `myText()` which is not defined here. that's why the error occurs!!

Comment: @KareemAbdelwahed Hope this helps you plus you can check out the link to I added to know more about variable scopes

Comment: @KareemAbdelwahed welcome :) you can accept/upvote the answer if it helps you plus let me know if you have any query regarding this querstion.

Comment: Instead of using `global` or `$GLOBALS`, the variable should be passed by reference, otherwise the function is too static and can't be used for other variables (if needed).

Answer (score 0):

you can use static or global to keep the value:

```
function doStuff() {
  $x = null;

  if ($x === null) {
     $x = 'changed';
     echo "changed.";
  }
}
doStuff();
doStuff();
```

the result would be: `changed.changed.`

if you use:

```
function doStuff() {
  static $x = null;

  if ($x === null) {
     $x = 'changed';
     echo "changed.";
  }
}
doStuff();
doStuff();
```

the result would be `changed.` because static keeps last value even if you call function in multi times
also global have the same result because of it's definition so you can also use:

```
global $x;
```

in the function and result would be same: `changed.`

Answer (score 0):

You have typo problem in your code (second calling of your function):

```
function myTest() ....
```

Then you called it:

```
myTeXt();
```